# How does one use Generic<T> base classes with CODEDUI Tests?

Tags: c#, generics, coded-ui-tests, composition

Codedui Tests require that the test class itself cannot be generic.  This means that code like this won't work:

```
[CodedUITest]
public class Test1<T> : BaseTestClass<T> where T: SomeType
```

This syntax is needed so that the test discovery tools can find the tests.

```
[CodedUITest]
public class Test1 : BaseTestClass
```

Dependeny Injection is then removed.  While there are plenty of other ways to do this...  Is there a way I can still use a Generic BaseTestClass?  This doesn't work because T is not defined..

```
[CodedUITest]
public class Test1 : BaseTestClass<T> where T: SomeType
```

This tells me that BaseTestClass does not take zero arguments:

```
[CodedUITest]
public class Test1 : BaseTestClass
```

Typically when I run into these types of issues I tend to "favor composition over inheritance"  which is a solution if I can't get by this one...  The Pattern looking like this:

```
[CodedUITest]
public class Test1 {
  public BaseTestClass Contained {get;set;}
     public void Test1(){
         Contained = new BaseTestClass<OfType>(); 
     }
}
```

Please Advise...

Comment: Woops I think I found the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just determined this works:

```
[CodedUITest]
 public class Test1 : BaseTestClass<InjectTypeHere>
```

doh!